# I have an issue with my code in VBA on excel that works in excel 97 but not in excel 16

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

i have a code that i have written that is working in a spreadsheet in excel 97 but not in 2016... the code is meant to take a table of data that is split in to 3 sections named....._Haz1..._Haz2..._Haz3.....

each of the items in each column have check boxes next to them it is a risk assessment sheet that when the code is running it should take all the ticked items and place them into a table below.

I have created a button and attatched the macro to the button so when ever you click the button it runs that specific macro......

when ever I click on the button it goes to run the code it moves down as if the items are being put into the table below but I just get a thick blue line and ni items in the table......

I am confused that it works in the previous excel 1997 but not in excel 2016

```
Option Explicit

Public iHazCount

Sub CompileHazards()

   iHazCount = 0

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Call ClearCompileArea

   Call FetchHazards(Range("Hazards!Haz1"), -3)
   Call FetchHazards(Range("Hazards!Haz2"), -4)
   Call FetchHazards(Range("Hazards!Haz3"), -7)

   ' set print area
   ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$Q$" & 80 + iHazCount

   Application.Goto Reference:=Range("A91"), Scroll:=True

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub FetchHazards(rHazList As Range, iDataOffset As Integer)

   Dim rHazCell As Range

   Dim iCurrRow As Integer

   For Each rHazCell In rHazList
      If rHazCell.Value = True Then
         ' calculate row postion
         iCurrRow = 81 + iHazCount
         ' first add line
         ' select bottom blank line and copy it down
          Range("A" & iCurrRow & ":Q" & 82 + iHazCount).Select
          Selection.Copy
          Range("A" & iCurrRow + 1).Select
          ActiveSheet.Paste
          ' go back to orig blank line and change blue bottom border
          Range("A" & iCurrRow & ":Q" & iCurrRow).Select
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
          With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
              .LineStyle = xlContinuous
              .Weight = xlThin
              .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          End With
         ' copy hazard
         Range("A" & iCurrRow).Value = rHazCell.Offset(0, iDataOffset).Value
         ' insert risk formula
         Range("P" & iCurrRow).Formula = "=IF(N" & iCurrRow & "*O" & iCurrRow & "< 7,""LOW"",IF(N" & iCurrRow & "*O" & iCurrRow & "< 11 ,""MID"",""HIGH""))"
         ' increment line count
         iHazCount = iHazCount + 1

      End If
   Next

End Sub

Sub ClearCompileArea()

   ' delete all rows below first
    Rows("83:121").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ' clear contents of first row
    Range("A81:Q81").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ' reinsert blue bottom border
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = 5
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Goto Reference:=Range("A91"), Scroll:=True`, on which sheet? same for other `Range` references, but otherwise I don't know why nothing is happening in Excel 2016...

Comment: There's nothing I see in there which has changed since Excel 97.  something else is different.  As @R3uK notes though, your code would be more robust if you specify a worksheet object every time you reference any range.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions and but still there is no change to the code it looks as if it is trying to grab the data because it creates the top row of the table and the bottom row but puts no data in the table I think it may be something to do with the check boxes but I cant figure out what it is.......